Thermofield Double state continuous energy spectrum
Consider a bipartite quantum mechanical system consisting of two identical systems $A$ and $B$. The thermofield double state of the combined system is then given as
\begin{align*}
    \left|TFD\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z}}\sum_n e^{-\beta \frac{E_n}{2}}\left|n_A\right>\otimes \left|n_B\right>
\end{align*}
I was wondering if one could also consider a thermofield double state when the energies $E_n$ of the subsystems are not discrete but can take every non negative real number. The obvious way to write such a state down would be
\begin{align*}
    \left|TFD\right>=\sqrt{\beta}\int_0^\infty dq e^{-\beta \frac{q}{2}}\left|q_A\right>\otimes \left|q_B\right>
\end{align*}
where $Z = \int dq e^{-\beta q}= 1/\beta$. However to me it is not clear what the energy eigenstates $\left|q\right>$ should be in this case. I also can't find anything in the literature about such a construction so i would be thankful if someone has a reference on this.

Interesting question. When the energy is in the continuous spectrum there are no eigenvectors so what you wrote indeed does not make sense. What still exists is the unitary that diagonalizes the Hamiltonian (like the Fourier transform for a free particle).

A trivial example of such a system would be a free particle in space. The energy eigenstates look like: $|q\rangle = |p\rangle$, where p is the momentum of the particle, and $q = p^2/2m$ is its energy. In this case, the product space is just the space $|q_A\rangle \otimes |q_B\rangle$ of two entangled particles. The total system Hamiltonian is:
$$
\hat{H}_{\text{TFD}} = \frac{\hat{p}^2_A}{2m} \otimes \mathbb{I}_B - \mathbb{I}_A \otimes \frac{\hat{p}^2_B}{2m} 
$$
And the eigenstates are just products of the momentum states of each particle.
Now this isn't that interesting in and of itself, but it turns out that you can extend this idea to use thermofields to talk about quantum field theories at finite temperature. Such a direction has been explored in many papers, for example Temporal description of thermal quantum fields (Umezawa, Yamanaka, 1992).
